# Using TortoiseGit with svn-git to clone specific branches of SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, tortoisegit

I have a SVN project with following architecture (empty `trunk` and `tags`)

```
https://svn-repo.com/svn/company
   +--my_project
   |  +--trunk (empty)
   |  +--branches
   |  |  +--my_branch
   |  |  +--my_branch2
   |  |  +--temp_branch1
   |  |  +--temp_branch2
   |  |  +--temp_branch3
   |  +-tags (empty)
```

I would like to use TortoiseGit to clone this repository into a git repository with branches `my_branch` and `my_branch2` and being able to commit changes back to SVN.

I have been able to clone a single branch by not checking any boxes related to Trunk, Tags, Branch and putting the URL to the branch (e.g. `https://svn-repo.com/svn/company/my_project/branches/my_branch`) and specifying the first SVN revision of the branch.

[image: TortoiseGit clone of SVN single branch]

I have tried to put the URL `https://svn-repo.com/svn/company/my_project` and checking all the boxes but this failed each time.

**Question 1**: How to clone the SVN repository with all its branches to Git through TortoiseGit?

**Question 2**: What is the way (if it exists) to only keep certain branches in the Git repository (namely, removing all the branches `temp_branchN`)?

I found a bit of if using git-svn CLI (like this [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385813/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-branches-after-cloning-just-trunk-in-git-svn)) but nothing relevant for TortoiseGit.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1** A mix of TortoiseGit + patch of config file (c.f. below)

**Question 2** Based on Lazy Barger hints, I came up with the following flow

1. TortoiseGit clone with only a selection of the trunk (revision 12345 corresponding to the creation of the tunk)

[image: TortoiseGit clone of SVN trunk]

2. `.git/config` file edited by hand to add the desired branches

The following shall be added in the `svn-remote` part

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://myserver:8443/svn/WorkRoot
    fetch = my_project/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = my_project/branches/my_branch*:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

3. TortoiseGit `SVN fetch` to pull out the branches

The last command might take a while because it starts searching from revision 1.

4. Perform TortoiseGit `Switch/Checkout` to change the branch

*Note: To perform the command equivalent to `svn update`, I use `Git SVN Rebase` and select the correct upstream corresponding to the remote branch (and not the trunk which is selected by default).*

[image: Git SVN Rebase]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't do it (in good way) in *pure* TortoiseGit
2. You have to edit `[svn-remote]` section in `$GIT_DIR/config` file by hand

[Git-SVN doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_configuration) mention some rare cases for Subversion repos and suggest possible solution: enumerating all needed (and only needed) branches

> Since some SVN repositories are oddly configured with multiple projects glob expansions such those listed below are allowed:
>
> ```
> [svn-remote "project-a"]
>     ...
>   branches = branches/*/project-a:refs/remotes/project-a/branches/*
>   branches = branches/release_*:refs/remotes/project-a/branches/release_*
>   branches = branches/re*se:refs/remotes/project-a/branches/*
>     ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks. So for question 1., what would be the non-pure way to do it?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. - `git svn init` + adding branch-keys + `git svn fetch`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will do some tests and come up with some specific flow.